# 絵文字の U+1F600 の U+ は「ユニコードの」を意味する接頭辞ですか？

Tags: 文字コード, unicode

にこやかな笑顔はユニコードで表すと `U+1F600` になりますが、この `U+` とは「ユニコードの」という意味なのでしょうか？
「ユニコードの1F600」という意味なのでしょうか？
2進数に変えて理解を深めたいなと思いまして。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> U+とはユニコードのという意味なのでしょうか？

そうです。
これは数値の一部では無く、印です。[Re: Origin of the U+nnnn notation](https://unicode.org/mail-arch/unicode-ml/y2005-m11/0060.html) によれば、元々は「⊎」（U+228E MULTISET UNION）という記号を使いたかったそうです。

そういう訳ですから、数値として扱う場合には U+ の部分は無視してよいです。`U+1F600` なら 16進表記の `1F600` が符号位置（コードポイント）です。

Answer (score 8):

「ユニコードの1F600」という意味で合っているでしょう。
(それと「2進数に変えて理解深めたい」とのつながりが不明ですが)

ただし気になることがあるなら、以下のように元々の仕様を探ってみましょう。

「unicode specification」というキーワードで検索すると[About the Unicode® Standard](https://unicode.org/standard/standard.html)というページとか出てきて、その左上に`Latest Version`というリンクがあり、それが現在の最新の仕様としてここで見ることが出来るでしょう。
[Unicode® 15.0.0](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode15.0.0/)
左側のメニューの「15.0.0 Chapters」に各章のタイトルとPDFへのリンクが列挙されています。

おそらく最初に記述されているのはここでしょう。
2 [General Structure](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode15.0.0/ch02.pdf)
ページ番号29ページ「2.4 Code Points and Characters」の最後に以下の記述があります。

> When referring to code points in the Unicode Standard, the usual practice is to refer to them by their numeric value expressed in hexadecimal, with a "U+" prefix. (See Appendix A, Notational Conventions.)
> Unicode 標準でコード ポイントを参照する場合、通常は、「U+」プレフィックスを付けて 16 進数で表した数値で参照します。 (付録 A、表記規則を参照してください。)

上記に書かれている`Appendix A`は「15.0.0 Appendices and Back Matter」の最初にあるこれですね。
A [Notational Conventions](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode15.0.0/appA.pdf)
このPDFとしては3ページ目、ページ番号は968ページ目の最初の方に以下のように記述されています。

> A.1 Typographic Conventions
> Code Points
> In running text, an individual Unicode code point is expressed as U+n, where n is four to six hexadecimal digits, using the digits 0–9 and uppercase letters A–F (for 10 through 15, respectively). Leading zeros are omitted, unless the code point would have fewer than four hexadecimal digits—for example, U+0001, U+0012, U+0123, U+1234, U+12345, U+102345.
> 実行中のテキストでは、個々の Unicode コード ポイントは U+n として表されます。ここで、n は 0 ～ 9 の数字と大文字の A ～ F (それぞれ 10 ～ 15) を使用した 4 ～ 6 桁の 16 進数です。コード ポイントが 4 桁未満の 16 進数でない限り、先行ゼロは省略されます (例: U+0001、U+0012、U+0123、U+1234、U+12345、U+102345)。

他にはWikipediaの日本語記事などでも情報は取得出来るでしょう。
[Unicode - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)
「文字集合」の段落？に以下の記述があります。

> Unicode符号位置を文章中などに記す場合は "U+" の後に十六進法で符号位置を4桁から6桁続けることで表す。